# Insert a string of text into an NSTextView at the cursor position or selection of text using Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

How would I do this using Objective C and cocoa using Xcode?
I am trying to insert a string at the cursor or user selection on the click of a button.

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE. The answer would be the same if you were using vi and make.

Answer (score 6):

NSTextView has a method -insertText: which does what you want:

```
[myTextView insertText:@"hello world"];
```

The method accepts either an NSString or an NSAttributedString.

Comment: This is now deprecated. Use `func insertText(_ string: Any, replacementRange: NSRange)` instead, now...