# how do I insert text at cursor position in a nstextview using cocoa programming?

Tags: cocoa

I am using this code to get the cursor position:

```
NSInteger insertionPoint = [[[myTextView selectedRanges] objectAtIndex:0] rangeValue].location;
```

How to add selected text at the current cursor position and not by appending the text?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insert a string of text into an NSTextView at the cursor position or selection of text using Objective C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057135/insert-a-string-of-text-into-an-nstextview-at-the-cursor-position-or-selection-o)

Comment: i mean to say if i copy the selected text and want to paste it at any cursor position how can i do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, this will work for you:

```
[textView setSelectedRange:NSMakeRange(4, 0)];
[textView insertText:@"my copied text"];
```

In the `NSMakeRange()` 4 is the location in the text view and 0 is used for the length because you don't want to replace any text.

Comment: Great, I'm glad it worked.  If you don't mind could you select my answer as your solution?